# Windows Server 2012 Memory Leak

Tags: visual-studio-2013, memory-leaks, server, bamboo, windows-server-2012-r2

I have non-pool memory value about 3 Gb from total 6 Gb on windows server 2012. I think it's memory leak, see screens:
[image]

Top process:
[image]

Bamboo uses Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 to build project and run tests.

1. How to determine bad process?
2. And how to solve problem? May be it's possible to dispose this leak?

Comment: Useful post:
https://danieladeniji.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/technical-microsoft-os-memory-tools-poolmon/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a memory leak caused by a driver, not by an application. Look at the high value of nonpaged kernel memory. In your case this is 2.7 GB. You can use [poolmon](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2012/08/30/troubleshooting-pool-leaks-part-2-poolmon.aspx) to see which driver is causing the high usage.

Install the [Windows WDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=393659), run poolmon, sort it via <kbd>P</kbd> after pool type so that non paged is on top and via <kbd>B</kbd> after bytes to see the tag which uses most memory. Run poolmon by going to the folder where WDK is installed, go to Tools (or C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Tools\x64) and click poolmon.exe.

Now look which pooltag uses most memory as shown here:

[image]

Now open a cmd prompt and run the findstr command. To do this, open cmd prompt and type "cd C:\Windows\System32\drivers" to go to the drivers directory, without quotes. Then type `findstr /s __ *.*`, where `__` is the tag that you see in poolmon.

After doing this to see which driver uses this tag:

[image]

Now, go to the drivers folder (C:\Windows\System32\drivers) and right-click the driver in question (`intmsd.sys` in the above image example). Click Properties, go to the details tab to find the Product Name. Look for an update for that product.

If you can't find a driver to the pooltag, look in the pooltag.txt if the tag is used by a Windows driver.

If you find the tag in the pooltag.txt, you need to capture a grow of the pool usage with [xperf](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx). First, you have to [install the Windows Performance Toolkit](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx). Next open a cmd prompt (cmd.exe) [as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) and run this:

> xperf -on BASE+Pool -stackwalk PoolAlloc+PoolFree -buffersize 2048
>   -MaxFile 1024 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d C:\trace_pool_alloc.etl

Now open it in [WPA.exe](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-48-WPT-Memory-Analysis-Pool#time=09m55s), [load the debug symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448108.aspx) and look for the tag that you saw in poomon under `AIFO` (*allocated insde freed outside*) and expend the stack. From the function names you may have any idea what is going on.

[image]

In this example the `FILE` tag usage comes from a tool called [locate32](http://locate32.cogit.net/) which scans the HDD to build up its search index.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!
Unfortunately, late yesterday I saw your post and reboot the server. Now, after 12 hours of work there is 120 MB non-paged pool memory.
[screen with poolmon](http://imgur.com/BHcNrQy)

Comment: ok, File is also your largest tag. So do the xperf trace when the file tag usage grows.

Comment: you need to open the C:\trace_pool_alloc.etl and load the symbols. Also move the stack to the left side of the yellow bar. Now also look at the count and size value and to see how many allocations (count) with how may bytes were done. I can't see the count column, so I can't answer this. But the whole AIFO is only 2.76MB, so this is small.

Comment: Xperf has process for about 6 hours: non-paged pool - 281 Mb [screen](http://i.imgur.com/FHIylNO.png) May be problem with AOFO File tag?

Comment: AOFO is no tag. AOFO stand for Allocated outside the trace ad free outside of the trace. So no loeak. You also have to look at AIFO, which allocated during trace, but NOT freed. If possible, share the ETL (send oneDrive share link to my username {a T ] Ao L (D o T] c O m), so that I can take a look at it.

Comment: ok, yes some of the FILE usage comes from csrss.exe. The trace is somehow corrupted, it misses the data to load debug symbols, but I see that RDPUDD.dll is used, so it looks like you use Remote Desktop Services and several users are logged into the server ( I see several csrss.exe, winlogon.exe and smss.exe processes). And this seams to sum up to the higher pool usage

Comment: After server restart I've traced memory with xperf for 12 hours. And now AOFO (File) occupies ~1 Gb and still growing. Is it possible to trace AOFO?

Comment: increase the filesize in the command to include more data in the trace (-MaxFile 3072). But working with large files is a pane in WPA. WPA is slow here.